# GetPrice Function Adds Zeros at the end

Tags: upgradeschema

I'm using this code for structured data.

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo $_product->getPrice(); ?>">
```

I get the price that I need but it adds ".0000" at the end.

Please advise on how to remove those ".0000" or may be use a different code to call the price field.

Comment: Are you on Magento 1 Or 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all zeros you can use:

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo (float) $_product->getPrice(); ?>">
```

Above code will remove all zeros.

If you want to keep specific number of zeros, you can use:

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo number_format($_product->getPrice(), 2); ?>">
```

Above code will keep only 2 zeros after decimal

Hope Above will help!

Comment: Good answer. +1

Comment: It worked. I used the first code you recommended. I entered . 4 to take out period and 4 zeros. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Glad to know @AlexT :). You can accept and up vote answer too :)

Comment: No problem :) where?

Comment: you just need to tick right icon, left to answer :)